# Is my solution to the "Sum of Range" exercise in Chapter4 of Eloquent JavaScript okay? Or is there a way to make it better?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

I started learning website development (just over 2 months now), learning frontend with HTML, CSS and JS. I am currently on the Eloquent JavaScript book. I did the "sum of range" exercise in chapter 4 of the book, I was able to code the range function, got a little help on the sum function, and competed the exercise. What I want now is to know how well written my solution is, and if there is a better way. This is the exercise and my code solution follows:

> Write a `range` function that takes two arguments, `start` and `end`, and returns an array containing all the numbers from `start` up to (and including) `end`.
>
> Next write a `sum` function that takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of these numbers.
>
> As a bonus assignment, modify your range function to take an optional third argument that indicates the "step" value used when building the array. If no step is given, the elements go up by increments of one, corresponding to the old behaviour. The function call `range(1, 10, 2)` should return `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`. Make sure it also works with negative step values so that `range(5, 2, -1)` returns `[5, 4, 3, 2]`.

My solution:

```
function range(start, end, skip) {
    let arr = [];
    let count;
    for (count = start;start < end ? count<=end : count >= end ; count+= skip) {
        arr.push(count);
    }
    return arr;
}

function sum(numbers) {
    result = 0;
    for (let num of numbers) {
        result += num;
    }
    return result;
}
```

All I need now is a somewhat "code inspection". Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As for your code, see [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).